# Unexpected behavior with await inside a ContinueWith block

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I have a slightly complex requirement of performing some tasks in parallel, and having to wait for some of them to finish before continuing. Now, I am encountering unexpected behavior, when I have a number of tasks, that I want executed in parallel, but inside a ContinueWith handler. I have whipped up a small sample to illustrate the problem:

```
var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("11");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("12");
}).ContinueWith(async t =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("13");
    var innerTasks = new List<Task>();
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var j = i;
        innerTasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1_" + j + "_1");
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            Console.WriteLine("1_" + j + "_2");
        }));
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(innerTasks.ToArray());
    //Task.WaitAll(innerTasks.ToArray());
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("14");
});
var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("21");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("22");
}).ContinueWith(t =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("23");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("24");
});
Console.WriteLine("1");
await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
Console.WriteLine("2");
```

The basic pattern is:
- Task 1 should be executed in parallel with Task 2.
- Once the first part of part 1 is done, it should do some more things in parallel. I want to complete, once everything is done.

I expect the following result:

```
1 <- Start
11 / 21 <- The initial task start
12 / 22 <- The initial task end
13 / 23 <- The continuation task start
Some combinations of "1_[0..9]_[1..2]" and 24 <- the "inner" tasks of task 1 + the continuation of task 2 end
14 <- The end of the task 1 continuation
2 <- The end
```

Instead, what happens, is that the `await Task.WhenAll(innerTasks.ToArray());` does not "block" the continuation task from completing. So, the inner tasks execute after the outer `await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);` has completed. The result is something like:

```
1 <- Start
11 / 21 <- The initial task start
12 / 22 <- The initial task end
13 / 23 <- The continuation task start
Some combinations of "1_[0..9]_[1..2]" and 24 <- the "inner" tasks of task 1 + the continuation of task 2 end
2 <- The end
Some more combinations of "1_[0..9]_[1..2]" <- the "inner" tasks of task 1
14 <- The end of the task 1 continuation
```

If, instead, I use `Task.WaitAll(innerTasks.ToArray())`, everything seems to work as expected. Of course, I would not want to use WaitAll, so I won't block any threads.

My questions are:

1. Why is this unexpected behavior occuring?
2. How can I remedy the situation without blocking any threads?

Thanks a lot in advance for any pointers!

Comment: Answer to question 1 is because ContinueWith runs its contents async, and nothing is waiting for them; you're waiting on task1, of which the continueWith is not a part.

Comment: It looks like you'd just want to make the "continueWith" part inline to task1 (instead of being continueWith) to achieve the desired result. That's really what you're saying. Do these steps in task 1, then these other tasks. That doesn't need a continueWith.

Comment: Inlining is not really an option, since the first Task is already something async, that needs to complete before the continuation is run. I could, of course, use a wrapping task, and inside that, simply await the first operation and then lauch the others. But then, I would have two tasks, where I think one should be enough. On the other hand, it seems that `ContinueWith` is doing just that by returning a `Task<Task<T>>`, so I guess it would not matter, where the extra Task comes from. Please correct me, if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong tools. Instead of `StartNew`, use `Task.Run`. Instead of `ContinueWith`, use `await`:

```
var task1 = Task1();
var task2 = Task2();
Console.WriteLine("1");
await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
Console.WriteLine("2");

private async Task Task1()
{
  await Task.Run(() =>
  {
    Console.WriteLine("11");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("12");
  });
  Console.WriteLine("13");
  var innerTasks = new List<Task>();
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    innerTasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
    {
      Console.WriteLine("1_" + i + "_1");
      Thread.Sleep(500);
      Console.WriteLine("1_" + i + "_2");
    }));
    await Task.WhenAll(innerTasks);
  }
  Thread.Sleep(1000);
  Console.WriteLine("14");
}

private async Task Task2()
{
  await Task.Run(() =>
  {
    Console.WriteLine("21");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("22");
  });
  Console.WriteLine("23");
  Thread.Sleep(1000);
  Console.WriteLine("24");
}
```

`Task.Run` and `await` are superior here because they correct a lot of unexpected behavior in `StartNew`/`ContinueWith`. In particular, asynchronous delegates and (for `Task.Run`) always using the thread pool.

I have more detailed info on my blog regarding [why you shouldn't use `StartNew`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/03/a-tour-of-task-part-9-delegate-tasks.html) and [why you shouldn't use `ContinueWith`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/01/a-tour-of-task-part-7-continuations.html).

Comment: Thank you for this. I think, it makes the code much more concise. Concerning `Task.Run(..)` and `Task.Factory.StartNew`, I have read various opinions, and we have even experienced problems using `Task.Run(..)` and switched to `.StartNew(..)` in some cases, however, I cannot find the explanation for that now. Apart from some reordering of code (`await Task.WhenAll(innerTasks);` should be outside of the `for` loop), and a modified closure issue with `i`, your code works like a charm. I was missing that the await inside the async method would yield and return control to the calling method.

Comment: I just noticed that your code simply repeated the same mistakes my original code also had with the `await Task.WhenAll(innerTasks);` in the wrong place, and the access to the modified closure. I have updated my code to reflect this. Thanks again, your answer was a big help.

Answer (score 3):

As noted [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40136943/unexpected-behavior-with-await-inside-a-continuewith-block#comment67543651_40136943), what you're seeing is normal. The `Task` returned by `ContinueWith()` completes when the delegate passed to and invoked by `ContinueWith()` finishes executing. This happens the first time the anonymous method uses the `await` statement, and the delegate returns a `Task` object itself that represents the eventual completion of the entire anonymous method.

Since you are only waiting on the `ContinueWith()` task, and this task only represents the *availability* of the task that represents the anonymous method, not the completion of that task, your code doesn't wait.

From your example, it's not clear what the best fix is. But if you make this small change, it will do what you want:

```
await Task.WhenAll(await task1, task2);
```

I.e. in the `WhenAll()` call, don't wait on the `ContinueWith()` task itself, but rather on the task *that* task will eventually return. Use `await` here to avoid blocking the thread while you wait for that task to be available.

Comment: Thanks, I had not realized, that `.ContinueWith()` returns a Task<Task<T>>. I thought, it would simply cascade, and the resulting task would be the "last" task in the chain. However, what I don't quite get then, is why using `Task.WaitAll(...)` instead of `await Task.WhenAll(...)` would also yield the expected result. I would want to think, it should make no difference, since this "Wait" is also happening, when the original task has already finished. If you can riddle me this, I'll gladly accept your answer.

Comment: _"why using Task.WaitAll(...)...would also yield the expected result"_ -- your post only mentions using `WaitAll(innerTasks.ToArray())`. The reason doing that prevents the bug from occurring is that doing so removes the `await` statement in your anonymous method that was causing it to return before the method completed. If you just `WaitAll()`, then the method blocks the thread until the entire method has completed (including the call to `WaitAll()`) instead of returning, to be continued later, at the `await` expression.

Comment: Hmmm, I think, I still don't quite grasp the concepts involved here. From what you wrote so far, I thought that `.WhenAll()` on the Task<Task> would wait for the original task to finish and then complete. But, now you're saying, that the inner task is executed, before the outer task is marked as completed. If I don't use `await` inside the continuation, it will mark the outer task as completed only after the whole continuation has run. However, if I do, it will mark the outer task as completed, once the inner task starts to wait for another async result?

Comment: You are confusing "the method has completed" with "the method has returned". It is _very_ important to understand the distinction. In the same way that a C# iterator method can _return_ (i.e. via `yield return`) before it has _completed_, so too can an `async` method, via `await`. An `async` method doesn't return its result; it returns a _task_ that represents that result. That task may not be (and usually is not) completed when the method returns from its initial caller. Later, the method will _complete_, and observers of the task that was returned earlier can see that when it happens.

Comment: A big thank you for explaining the yield vs. return part. I hadn't quite grasped that. This also explains why @stephen-cleary 's solution works the way it does. I would have thought, the calling method would also wait before continuing with the task2 initialization, but this explains the behavior consicely.

Answer (score 1):

When using async methods/lambdas with `StartNew`, you either wait on the returned task **and** the contained task:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => { /* ... */ });
task.Wait();
task.Result.Wait();
// consume task.Result.Result
```

Or you use the extension method `Unwrap` on the result of `StartNew` and wait on the task it returns.

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => { /* ... */ })
    .Unwrap();
task.Wait();
// consume task.Result
```

---

The following discussion goes along the line that `Task.Factory.StartNew` and `ContinueWith` should be avoided in specific cases, such as when you don't provide creation or continuation options or when you don't provide a task scheduler.

I don't agree that `Task.Factory.StartNew` shouldn't be used, I agree that you should use (or consider using) `Task.Run` wherever you use a `Task.Factory.StartNew` method overload that doesn't take `TaskCreationOptions` or a `TaskScheduler`.

Note that this only applies to the default `Task.Factory`.  I've used custom task factories where I chose to use the `StartNew` overloads without options and task scheduler, because I configured the factories specific defaults for my needs.

Likewise, I don't agree that `ContinueWith` shouldn't be used, I agree that you should use (or consider using) `async`/`await` wherever you use a `ContinueWith` method overload that doesn't take `TaskContinuationOptions` or a `TaskScheduler`.

For instance, up to C# 5, the most practical way to workaround the limitation of `await` not being supported in `catch` and `finally` blocks is to use `ContinueWith`.

C# 6:

```
try
{
    return await something;
}
catch (SpecificException ex)
{
    await somethingElse;
    // throw;
}
finally
{
    await cleanup;
}
```

Equivalent before C# 6:

```
return await something
    .ContinueWith(async somethingTask =>
    {
        var ex = somethingTask.Exception.InnerException as SpecificException;
        if (ex != null)
        {
            await somethingElse;
            // await somethingTask;
        }
    },
        CancellationToken.None,
        TaskContinuationOptions.DenyChildAttach | TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnRanToCompletion,
        TaskScheduler.Default)
    .Unwrap()
    .ContinueWith(async catchTask =>
    {
        await cleanup;
        await catchTask;
    },
        CancellationToken.None,
        TaskContinuationOptions.DenyChildAttach,
        TaskScheduler.Default)
    .Unwrap();
```

Since, as I told, in some cases I have a `TaskFactory` with specific defaults, I've defined a few extension methods that take a `TaskFactory`, reducing the error chance of not passing one of the arguments (I known I can always forget to pass the factory itself):

```
public static Task ContinueWhen(this TaskFactory taskFactory, Task task, Action<Task> continuationAction)
{
    return task.ContinueWith(continuationAction, taskFactory.CancellationToken, taskFactory.ContinuationOptions, taskFactory.Scheduler);
}

public static Task<TResult> ContinueWhen<TResult>(this TaskFactory taskFactory, Task task, Func<Task, TResult> continuationFunction)
{
    return task.ContinueWith(continuationFunction, taskFactory.CancellationToken, taskFactory.ContinuationOptions, taskFactory.Scheduler);
}

// Repeat with argument combinations:
// - Task<TResult> task (instead of non-generic Task task)
// - object state
// - bool notOnRanToCompletion (useful in C# before 6)
```

Usage:

```
// using namespace that contains static task extensions class
var task = taskFactory.ContinueWhen(existsingTask, t => Continue(a, b, c));
var asyncTask = taskFactory.ContinueWhen(existingTask, async t => await ContinueAsync(a, b, c))
    .Unwrap();
```

I decided not to mimic `Task.Run` by not overloading the same method name to unwrapping task-returning delegates, it's really not always what you want.  Actually, I didn't even implement `ContinueWhenAsync` extension methods so you need to use `Unwrap` or two `await`s.

Often, these continuations are I/O asynchronous operations, and the pre- and post-processing overhead should be so small that you shouldn't care if it starts running synchronously up to the first yielding point, or even if it completes synchronously (e.g. using an underlying `MemoryStream` or a mocked DB access).  Also, most of them don't depend on a synchronization context.

Whenever you apply the `Unwrap` extension method or two `await`s, you should check if the task falls in this category.  If so, `async`/`await` is most probably a better choice than starting a task.

For asynchronous operations with a non-negligible synchronous overhead, starting a new task may be preferable.  Even so, a notable exception where `async`/`await` is still a better choice is if your code is async from the start, such as an `async` method invoked by a framework or host (ASP.NET, WCF, NServiceBus 6+, etc.), as the *overhead* is your actual business.  For long processing, you may consider using `Task.Yield` with care.  One of the tenets of asynchronous code is to not be too fine grained, however, too coarse grained is just as bad: a set of heavy-duty tasks may prevent the processing of queued lightweight tasks.

If the asynchronous operation depends on a synchronization context, you can still use `async`/`await` if you're within that context (in this case, think twice or more before using `.ConfigureAwait(false)`), otherwise, start a new task using a task scheduler from the respective synchronization context.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this in detail explanation. This really helps in understanding all the concepts involved. I will, however, keep the @stephen-cleary's answer as the correct answer, as it solves my issue and makes the code nice and concise.